# Maven placeholder processor plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, placeholder

There is a task to process placeholders in ejb xml descriptors time during a compilation. 
For example {app.name}-Bean must become App-Bean if app.name=App.
In ideal way this should be supported by m2e life cycle plugin systems, to support deploy from the Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check if you can use the `filtering` property provided by [`<resources>`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) section of the pom for this.

You can define `<filters>` which can get applied.

Comment: If this doesnt fit for you, try: maven-replacer-plugin